# What's the right way to implement rights for a team?

Tags: sharing, roles

What is the best way to implement teams in Salesforce? Let's say we have a Team of three members, and each member should be able to edit and maintain records of the other member. How would you do that?

Would you use Sharing Rules and then say "If owner x then assign queue y"?

Could you use something like teams?

I really didn't do that much with rights and I am stuck with what is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first look at using a role based rule (if it makes sense for the 3 to be in a single role and nobody else is in that role).  That often is not the case, in which case I would use a public group, as you can use a standard owner-based rule to share from the group members to the group members read/write.

Why?  Because you are more limited in the number of criteria-based rules you can write per object, and to identify a specific user to share from, you need to use a criteria based rule on owner ID.  You can share from/to public groups using a standard ownership based rule.

I think this is easier to read/maintain.  Even though there still is no description field on public groups, which would be tremendously helpful, if you use a good naming convention on your public groups, then its reasonably feasible to track down who has access to what.

Exhibit A: public group based rule
[image: public group based rule]

If you use a criteria-based rule, you only have the UserID to try and work with, which for the average non-cyborg human, is typically more challenging.

Exhibit B: criteria based rule on owner
[image: owner based rule]

As you can see from the pics above, we have rules based on owner, but that was from before my time.  I think using roles / groups is the way to go for this type of need.

Here is a [good link](https://www.shellblack.com/administration/groups/) to a blog post reviewing this type of sharing (from before crtieria based rules even existed).  I dont know believe there are any speed / efficiency considerations here, i think that would work out the same, unless you had a large number of records shared from a single user, which is not recommended in the [large data volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_best_practices_general.htm) implementation guide.

> Avoiding sharing computations Avoid having any user own more than
>   10,000 records.

Comment: You are right. Roles and role based rules are the best way to do this. Worked like a charm.